# Cannot change action bar background color using resource file in Android

Tags: android

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I start learning Android development. I am trying to change my action bar background color. Anyway, I am overriding the action bar background color. But it is not working. I am doing this way.

This is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/whitesmoke</item>
    </style>

    <style name="actionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is my colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="light_blue">#6dbcd4</color>
    <color name="white">#FFF6F7F7</color>
    <color name="whitesmoke">#FFD3D5D6</color>
</resources>
```

I did this referenced on a online tutorial. Why it is not working? It just keep showing the dark color background all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using AppCompat, the item `android:actionBarStyle` is not used. Internally, AppCompat uses an item `actionBarStyle` without the android scope.

Nevertheless, the "new" way to color the default action bar with AppCompat is by setting your primary color:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked , i will hit the green soon . So please can I know the old way as well that is what I am doing ?

Comment: When I say the "new" way, I speak since Android Lollipop, when they added this concept of colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, and colorAccent. How it was done the "old" way, depends on if you were using the internal Android themes or if you were using AppCompat, which hides the default Android ActionBar and adds its custom implementation. If you were using normal Android themes, the way to do it was just as in your code above, except you would normally set a parent to your actionbar style like `<style name="actionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">` Holo was the theme before Material

Comment: Also, ActionBar is NOT deprecated as the other answer says. AppCompat will still show an ActionBar by default in its themes. ToolBar was added as an alternative, so that have a better control of your bar in the view hierarchy or you can use more than one bar.

Comment: Thanks for answer in details.

Answer (score 0):

1.action bar is deprecated.
2.better use toolbar.

sample cod:

layout/partial_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

you can change background color

menu/toolbar_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toggle_drawer"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_toggle"
        android:title="toggle_drawer"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

and in your activity/xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/partial_toolbar"/>
```

and in activity/java:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
```

and in values/stayles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</resources>
```

values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="purple">#b612bc</color>
    <color name="darker_gray">#aaa</color>
    <color name="light_gray">#d6d6d6</color>
    <color name="holo_blue_light">#ff33b5e5</color>
    <color name="black_slow">#181818</color>
    <color name="green_light">#6cd652</color>
    <color name="red_dirty">#dc6060</color>
    <color name="black_slowest">#b6262626</color>
</resources>
```